# Angular2-Meteor : Database (mysql) closing error

Tags: mysql, meteor, typescript, angular, angular2-meteor

Am using mysql within my angular2-meteor app , am trying to conclude a full transaction including opening , inserting ... and **closing** my database.

i'm confronting a problem of a closed socket which causes a full crash of my app when i'm closing it , here is my code and the error ,

***if there is any propositions ???***

*** My code :***

**1) Main.ts**

```
import {loaduser} from "./load-users";

if(Meteor.isServer){
   Meteor.onConnection(loaduser)
}
```

***2) My function :(load-users.ts)***

```
var Users:  Mysql.Collection<any>;
var db : Mysql.MeteorDatabase;
export function loaduser() {

        if(!db) {
            connexion();
        }
    traitement();
```

> db.end(function(err){   //the error is here
>           });

```
        function connexion() {
            var connectionSettings = {
                host: 'localhost',
                user: 'root',
                port: 3300,
                password: '',
                database: 'my_db'
            };
     db = Mysql.connect(connectionSettings);
        }
    function traitement (){

        Users = db.meteorCollection<Object>("users", "usersCollection");
        console.log("condition " + Users.find().count());
    }

};
```

***3) The error :***

> W20160413-16:37:48.281(2)? (STDERR)         throw err;
>   W20160413-16:37:48.281(2)? (STDERR)               ^
>   W20160413-16:37:48.281(2)? (STDERR) Error: This socket is closed.
>   W20160413-16:37:48.281(2)? (STDERR)     at Socket._write
>   (net.js:638:19)

**ANy ideas ?**